# Chrome : drag and drop absolute div inside contenteditable div

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop, contenteditable

Is it possible with Chrome to drag & drop a div in absolute position inside a contenteditable div?

The below code works with firefox and IE but not with Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<script>
  //for IE
  document.execCommand("2D-position",false,true); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div contenteditable="true" style="background-color:blue;width:900px;height:400px;position:relative;">
  <div style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:50px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately no...

Comment: Darn, thanks for the reply though